# Problemas com posicionamento de um elemento

Tags: html, css

Quero deixar a data fixada no canto direito, considerando que a `div` está a ser criada por um `while` e que a posição da data não dependa da extensão da descrição.

```html
<div style="background-color:grey;">
    <P>
        <a href=""><font size='5px'>Titulo</font></a><br>
        <p class="descricao_noticia"><font color='black' size='4px'>Descricao noticia</font></p>
        <font color='black' size='4px'>data</font>    
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolvi desta forma

```html
<div style="background-color:grey;height:180px; position: relative;">
    <P>
        <a href=""><font size='5px'>Titulo</font></a><br>
        <p class="descricao_noticia"><font color='black' size='4px'>Descricao noticia</font></p>
<div style='position: absolute; top: 40%;bottom:1%;right:1%;margin: 10% 0 0 10%;'  >data</div>  
    </P>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Tens de colocar o `display:inline-block` e `float` à direita.

```css
.descricao_noticia{
  width:80%;
  display:inline-block;
}

.data{
  text-align:right;
  display:inline-block;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:grey;">
<P>
  
  <a href=""><font size='5px'>Titulo</font> </a>
  <br>
  <p class="descricao_noticia">
    <font color='black' size='4px'>Descricao noticia<br>Descrição Notícia<br>Descrição Notícia<br>Descrição Notícia</font>
  </p>   
  <p class="data"><font color='black' size='4px' id="data">data</font></p>
</P>
</div>
```

Comment: O problema é que eu quero colocar a seguir a descrição e assim como está depende da descrição se a descrição tiver mais uma linha a data vai ficar mais abaixo

Comment: Não tinha percebido, já está corrigido

Comment: Não tinha percebido, já está corrigido

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma mais simples é usar `absolute` e `padding` ficando exatamente assim:

```css
.right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
```

```html
<div class="right">
  data
</div>
```